# Cannot find javadb client jar file for glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I have wrote a simple EJB application and going to test it through a java application client. For that i am fetching the bean as below,

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
        "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
// glassfish default port value will be 3700,
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
initialContext = new InitialContext(props);
helloWorld = (HelloWorldBean) initialContext
    .lookup("HelloWorldBean/remote");
```

But i am getting below exception followed by lot of other null pointers,

> 03-Dec-2012 22:37:37
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl
>   findDerbyClient INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc
>   driver will not be available by default. java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Orb initialization erorr  at
>   org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:148)

I add this jar even in to build path but still the exception occured. Even i can found the derbyclient jar is there under glassfish\javadb\lib

Also i need to verify whether i run this client correctly?

its just after deploy the application, right click on client class and run as java application right?